# How to perform post build action in WDK?

Tags: build, wdk

I'm trying to make a test driver with WinDDK. The "build" command works well following the technical instruction. Now what I want to do is that I want "build" to copy the build out to a certain directory. I'm familiar with linux make, so I added:

```
 install:
     copy sys\i386\myddk.sys c:\
```

to the makefile. But it didn't work at all.

How to make changes in makefile or sources file to let build copy the build out to somewhere?